# Copying one Azure blob to another blob in Azure Storage Client 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

In the old 1.7 storage client there was a CloudBlob.CopyFromBlob(otherBlob) method, but it does not seem to be present in the 2.0 version. What is the recommended best practice for copying blobs? I do see a ICloudBlob.BeginStartCopyFromBlob method. If that is the appropriate method, how do I use it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Gaurav Mantri](http://gauravmantri.com/) has written a series of articles on Azure Storage on version 2.0. I have taken this code extract from his blog post of [Storage Client Library 2.0 – Migrating Blob Storage Code](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/11/28/storage-client-library-2-0-migrating-blob-storage-code/) for Blob Copy

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(targetContainerName);
string blobName = "<Blob Name e.g. myblob.txt>";
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
targetBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(sourceBlob);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this to make a copy of a blob within the same storage account but I'm getting a 409 CONFLICT error. The message is that "The blob type is invalid for this operation". I've tried treating it as both a Page blob and a Block blob (I'm pretty sure i's a Page blob)

Comment: Resolved it. Turns out the source was a Page blob, but the destination had already been created (in a previous failed attempt) as a Block blob. Deleting the destination and trying again worked.

Comment: Is this server side copy?

Answer (score 35):

Using Storage 6.3 (much newer library than in original question) and async methods use StartCopyAsync ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopyasync(v=azure.100).aspx))

```
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Your Connection");

  CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("YourContainer");

  CloudBlockBlob source = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Your Blob");
  CloudBlockBlob target = container.GetBlockBlobReference("Your New Blob");
        
  await target.StartCopyAsync(source);
```

Answer (score 20):

FYI as of the latest version (7.x) of the `SDK` this no longer works because the `BeginStartCopyBlob` function no longer exists.

You can do it this way:

```
// this tunnels the data via your program,
// so it reuploads the blob instead of copying it on service side
using (var stream = await sourceBlob.OpenReadAsync())
{
  await destinationBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
}
```

As mentioned by @(Alexey Shcherbak) this is a better way to proceed:

```cs
await targetCloudBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceCloudBlob.Uri);

while (targetCloudBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    // Need to fetch or "CopyState" will never update
    await targetCloudBlob.FetchAttributesAsync(); 
}

if (targetCloudBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Success)
{
    throw new Exception("Copy failed: " + targetCloudBlob.CopyState.Status);
}
```

Comment: this will re-upload the blob. As Aaron Sherman mentioned - with newer library one should use StartCopyAsync

Comment: If you could add Vangaorth's FetchAttributes() amendment inline that might be useful - I hadn't seen until after a fair bit of debugging.

Comment: Starting Windows Azure Storage 8.0 you need to constantly fetch attributes as well ( targetCloudBlob.FetchAttributes() ). Snippet above will fail due timeout (endless loop).

Comment: targetCloudBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceCloudBlob.Uri) needs to be awaited.

Answer (score 18):

Starting Azure Storage 8, to move Blobs between Storage Accounts I use code similar to below, hope it will help somebody:

```
//copy blobs - from
CloudStorageAccount sourceStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(storageFromName, storageFromKey), true);
CloudBlobClient sourceCloudBlobClient = sourceStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = sourceCloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerFromName);

//copy blobs - to
CloudStorageAccount targetStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(storageToName, storageToKey), true);
CloudBlobClient targetCloudBlobClient = targetStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer targetContainer = targetCloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerToName);

//create target container if didn't exists
try{
    await targetContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
}
catch(Exception e){
    log.Error(e.Message);
}

CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

try{
    //initialize copying
    await targetBlob.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlob.Uri);
}
catch(Exception ex){
    log.Error(ex.Message);
    //return error, in my case HTTP
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Error, source BLOB probably has private access only: " +ex.Message);
} 

//fetch current attributes
targetBlob.FetchAttributes();

//waiting for completion
while (targetBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending){
    log.Info("Status: " + targetBlob.CopyState.Status);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    targetBlob.FetchAttributes();
}

//check status
if (targetBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Success){
    //return error, in my case HTTP
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Copy failed with status: " + targetBlob.CopyState.Status);
}

//finally remove source in case Copy Status was Success
sourceBlob.Delete();

//and return success (in my case HTTP)
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Done.");
```

Answer (score 13):

It seems that the API might have been cleaned up a little since previous posts were made.

```cs
// _client is a BlobServiceClient injected via DI in the constructor.

BlobContainerClient sourceContainerClient = _client.GetBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName);
BlobClient sourceClient = sourceContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

BlobContainerClient destContainerClient = _client.GetBlobContainerClient(destContainerName);
BlobClient destClient = destContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

// assume that if the following doesn't throw an exception, then it is successful.
CopyFromUriOperation operation = await destClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceClient.Uri);
await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();
```

The documentation for `operation.WaitForCompletionAsync` says:

> Periodically calls the server till the long-running operation completes.  This method will periodically call UpdateStatusAsync till HasCompleted is true, then return the final result of the operation.

Reviewing the source code for this method seems to call `BlobBaseClient.GetProperties` (or the async version) which will throw an `RequestFailureException` on error.

Comment: Thanks.  This works well for making sure the file was copied in real time.
This is wonderful  WaitForCompletionAsync();

Answer (score 11):

Naveen already explained the correct syntax for using `StartCopyFromBlob` (the synchronous method). The method you mentioned (`BeginStartCopyFromBlob`) is the asynchronous alternative which you can use in combination with a `Task` for example:

```
    var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Upload picture.
    var picturesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("pictures");
    picturesContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
    var myPictureBlob = picturesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("me.png");
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg", FileMode.Open))
        myPictureBlob.UploadFromStream(fs);

    // Backup picture.
    var backupContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("backup");
    backupContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
    var backupBlob = picturesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("me.png");

    var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<string>(backupBlob.BeginStartCopyFromBlob(myPictureBlob, null, null), backupBlob.EndStartCopyFromBlob);
    task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        if (!t.IsFaulted)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Copy state for {0}: {1}", backupBlob.Uri, backupBlob.CopyState.Status);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + t.Exception);
        }
    });
```

Comment: StartCopyFromBlob is also an asynchronous operation because [copy blob operation is asynchronous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

For me, WindowsAzure.Storage 8.0.1, James Hancock's solution did the server side copy but the client copy status was stuck on `Pending` (looping forever). Solution was to call `FetchAttributes()` on `targetCloudBlob` after `Thread.sleep(500)`.

```
// Aaron Sherman's code 

targetCloudBlob.StartCopy(sourceCloudBlob.Uri);

while (targetCloudBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    targetCloudBlob.FetchAttributes();
}

// James Hancock's remaining code
```

[Official Microsoft documentation (async example)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.copystate.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

here is my short simple answer.

```
public void Copy(CloudBlockBlob srcBlob, CloudBlobContainer destContainer)
{
    CloudBlockBlob destBlob;

    if (srcBlob == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Source blob cannot be null.");
    }

    if (!destContainer.Exists())
    {
        throw new Exception("Destination container does not exist.");
    }

    //Copy source blob to destination container
    string name = srcBlob.Uri.Segments.Last();
    destBlob = destContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
    destBlob.StartCopyAsync(srcBlob);                
}
```