# Copying large amount of data on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

What is the proper way of copying large amount of data from one location to another in Azure Blob storage and being able to check when the copy process is completed.

It seems there are a few Async and Copy, BeginCopy even in the SDK and its hard to figure out in what calls that I am quantied that the copy is done when the call completes, or if that assumption even holds. Should I check when a copy is done if its actually is done, as I think that all the SDK call just stats the copy process and Azure does the copy async in the back ground.

Comment: There's a tool called `azcopy` which might helps to you, but I'm not sure. Please check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/04/01/azcopy-using-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx

Comment: I'd recommend you check this existing SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152087/copying-one-azure-blob-to-another-blob-in-azure-storage-client-2-0

Comment: If it's a *lot* of data, you can also send in a bitlocker protected hard drive. You didn't mention how much data it was. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/

Comment: Maybe I formulated my question wrong. I am not interested in sending a harddrive, the data is already located in azure. I am not interested in a Tool for it. I am interested in knowing what happens behind the seen when you send a request for a copy, how long it takes and if the copyed fill will be hidden until its done copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [Copy Blob REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894037.aspx) documentation for more information on this.

In short, when a Copy Blob request is received, it will be processed by the Blob service either synchronously or asynchronously. However, please note that the Blob service copies blobs on a best-effort basis.

When copying from a page blob, the Blob service creates a destination page blob of the source blob’s length, initially containing all zeroes. When copying from a block blob, the Blob service creates a committed blob of zero length before returning from this operation. The final blob will be committed when the copy completes.