# Azure Blob Storage - Copy production to development

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We're using blob storage in our MVC app to store thousands of photos across hundreds of containers. We have a storage account for production and a storage account for development. While in development, we write all photos to the development storage account.

Periodically we'd like to completely clear out our development storage account and copy everything from our development storage account. This will include hundreds of containers and files within those containers.

I'm aware of AzCopy but there doesn't seem to be a way or easy way to do what we want to do. For example, I don't want to have to copy all files container by container etc.

Is there a way to do what we want?

Comment: is this what you need? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806401.aspx. you can copy across subsciptions and regions without downloading any of it

Comment: I don't think so, but thanks.

Comment: I meant these really. https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-Storage-Cmdlets 
I've used them to duplicate copies of live media dumps for dev purposes..or do you mean copy them to a local drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write a tiny CopyBlob program that takes the constraints and calls AzCopy with required params to copy over required blobs.

[Update]

You can use [Azure Storage Library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) and [StartCopyFromBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj732079.aspx) method to copy blob. If you are not using .Net, you can find equivalent in azure storage library written in other languages as well.

This copy blob is asynchronous in nature meaning 'without having to retrieve the content', saves cost and time. More details on [Azure Storage Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-asynchronous-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14152210/147613) shows how to copy blob, just for completion.

Comment: It seems to me that if I'm going to write a CopyBlob program, I would just do so using the Azure API in a C# program instead of trying to decipher all the parameters in AzCopy.

Comment: I think it'll be more than 10 lines of code, but writing a C# app might be the approach I need to take.