# Does CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync return when the copy is completed?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

There are several ways to copy azure blob storage blocks around. There's a synchronous and asynchronous version of `StartCopy`. There is also a `BeginStartCopy` which also has the completion callback.

The `BeginStartCopy` approach explicitly states that the callback is executed when the copy has completed.

The `StartCopy` approaches both state that they return a string, which is a copy process id - they don't state that they return when the copy has completed.

Do those `StartCopy` methods return after the actual copy has completed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `StartCopy()` and `await StartCopyAsync()` return when the copy is **started** on Azure Blob Storage service. The completion callback of `BeginStartCopy()` is also executed when the copy is **started** on Azure Blob Storage service.

In conclusion, `StartCopy` (including all 3 versions above) is an asynchronous API, you need to call `FetchAttributes()` periodically by yourself to get the latest copy progress.

Here is an answer that you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651946/2995449

Comment: "The completion callback of `BeginStartCopy()` is also executed when the copy is *started*"? Is that a typo? As OP mentions, the documentation clearly states that the callback is notified upon completion of the operation.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman It's NOT a typo. The callback is notified upon the completion of **StartCopy**, rather than the completion of **Copy**.

Comment: Is this still true if both source and destination for the copy are in the same storage account? [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-copy?tabs=dotnet11#about-copying-blobs) mentions that under the same storage account copying is a synchronous operation.