# Rename blob then save new

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I am trying to use Xamarin Blob to save the new version of a image after renaming the previous one.
for example my old image is in the container named "imagecontainer" and  has Id named like "xama_452"

```
what I would like to do is :

1- Rename the old image name : for example 'xama_452_11_2018"
2-Move it in a container "oldcontainer"
3- then save the new image in "imagecontainer"
```

I have tried some code I can upload a image/blob but I cannot rename it and move it to another container.

```
 protected static async Task<CloudBlockBlob> SaveBlockBlob(string containerName, byte[] blob, string blobTitle)
        {

            var blobContainer = GetBlobContainer(containerName);
            var blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobTitle);

            var oldBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blockBlob.Uri.ToString());
            var newBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blockBlob.Uri.ToString().Replace(blobTitle, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()+ blobTitle));


            await newBlob.StartCopyAsync(oldBlob);

// here is the methode to upload
            // await blockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(blob, 0, blob.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return blockBlob;
        }

// method to get blob's container 
 static CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(string containerName) => BlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Storage Blob Rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734672/azure-storage-blob-rename)

Comment: It it not the sae I want to rename the old image file , if you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Rename the old image name : for example 'xama_452_11_2018"

Due to the lack of API to rename the blob file on Azure, you could set newBlobName with the format you want and copy the source to the destination. Refer to this [article](https://riptutorial.com/azure/example/19255/renaming-a-blob-file-in-azure-blob-storage).

> 2-Move it in a container "oldcontainer"

You could get the desctionation container's blob to copy the source. Refer to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260583/azure-storage-move-blob-to-other-container).

> 3- then save the new image in "imagecontainer"

Upload blob to the sourcecontainer. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows#upload-blobs-to-the-container).

The whole codes are as below:

```
public static void RenameBlob(string containerName, string destContainer,string blobName,string newblobname)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer imgcontainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    string[] name = blobName.Split('.');
    //rename blob
    string newBlobName = name[0] + "_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("MM")+"_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + "." + name[1];
    CloudBlobContainer oldcontainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(destContainer);
    if (!oldcontainer.Exists())
    {
        throw new Exception("Destination container does not exist.");
    }
    CloudBlockBlob blobCopy = oldcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(newBlobName);
    if (!blobCopy.Exists())
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = imgcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        if (blob.Exists())
        {
            //move blob to oldcontainer
            blobCopy.StartCopy(blob);
            blob.Delete();
        }
    }
    //upload blob to imagecontainer
    CloudBlockBlob cloudblobnew = imgcontainer.GetBlockBlobReference(newblobname);
    cloudblobnew.UploadFromFileAsync(newfile);
}
```

If your still have any problem, please feel free to let me know. Hope it helps you.