# How to copy an Azure File to an Azure Blob?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I've got some files sitting in an Azure File storage.

I'm trying to programatically archive them to Azure Blobs and I'm not sure how to do this *efficiently*.

I keep seeing [code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152087/copying-one-azure-blob-to-another-blob-in-azure-storage-client-2-0) about copying from one blob container to another blob container .. but not from a *File to a Blob*.

Is it possible to do without downloading the entire File content locally and then uploading this content? Maybe use Uri's or something?

More Info:

1. The File and Blob containers are in the same Storage account.
2. The storage account is `RA-GRS`

Here was some sample code I was *thinking* of doing .. but it just doesn't feel right :( (pseudo code also .. with validation and checks omitted).

```
var file = await ShareRootDirectory.GetFileReference(fileName);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);

    // Custom method that basically does:
    // 1. GetBlockBlobReference
    // 2. UploadFromStreamAsync
    await cloudBlob.AddItemAsync("some-container", stream);
}
```

Comment: If it is useful, please help to mark it as answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: and @TomSun-MSFT .. same goes for the question :) If useful, upvote :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to copy an Azure File to an Azure Blob?

We also can use [CloudBlockBlob.StartCopy(CloudFile)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt433224.aspx). `CloudFile` type is also can be accepted by the CloudBlockBlob.StartCopy function.
How to copy CloudFile to blob please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files). The following demo code is snippet from the document.

```
// Parse the connection string for the storage account.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to File storage.
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

// Create a new file share, if it does not already exist.
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("sample-share");
share.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create a new file in the root directory.
CloudFile sourceFile = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("sample-file.txt");
sourceFile.UploadText("A sample file in the root directory.");

// Get a reference to the blob to which the file will be copied.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("sample-container");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
CloudBlockBlob destBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("sample-blob.txt");

// Create a SAS for the file that's valid for 24 hours.
// Note that when you are copying a file to a blob, or a blob to a file, you must use a SAS
// to authenticate access to the source object, even if you are copying within the same
// storage account.
string fileSas = sourceFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
{
    // Only read permissions are required for the source file.
    Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
});

// Construct the URI to the source file, including the SAS token.
Uri fileSasUri = new Uri(sourceFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + fileSas);

// Copy the file to the blob.
destBlob.StartCopy(fileSasUri);
```

Note:

> If you are copying a blob to a file, or a file to a blob, **you must use a shared access signature (SAS) to authenticate the source object, even if you are copying within the same storage account**.

Comment: The code above will not work as is. One would need to create a SAS URI for the file and use that in StartCopy(). Please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Transfer Manager:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.datamovement.transfermanager_methods.aspx

There are methods to copy from CloudFile to CloudBlob.

Add the "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement" nuget package

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement;

private string _storageConnectionString = "your_connection_string_here";

public async Task CopyFileToBlob(string blobContainer, string blobPath, string fileShare, string fileName)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionString);
    CloudFileShare cloudFileShare = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference(fileShare);
    CloudFile source = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference(fileName);

    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(blobContainer);
    CloudBlockBlob target = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobPath);

    await TransferManager.CopyAsync(source, target, true);
}
```